# Understanding angular-material gridList

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I was going through angular-material [gridList](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList). You can see the example in codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwWprd). I want to understand what following attributes means in this example and how to use them. documentation seems silent on it.

```
md-cols-sm
md-cols-md
md-cols-gt-md
md-row-height-gt-md
md-row-height
md-gutter
md-gutter-gt-sm
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can actually get the meaning of these from angular material docs here:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList

And

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

You may notice here, that, -sm-, -md-, and -lg- are basically `media-query-name` that are meant to target small, medium, and large devices, respectively.

Now, as per your question,

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6" md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="2:2" md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">
```

basically means to create a grid list, which has:

"One" column/grid in small devices (`md-cols-sm="1"`),

"Two" columns/grids in medium devices (`md-cols-md="2"`) and

"Six" columns/grids in devices greater than 960px wide (`md-cols-gt-md="6"`).

Next, ( `md-row-height-gt-md="1:1"`) means that the Ratio of width to height in devices greater than 960px width should be 1:1.

( `md-row-height="2:2"`) means that the Ratio of width to height should be 2:2.

( `md-gutter="12px"`) means that the amount of space between tiles should be 12 px.

( `md-gutter-gt-sm="8px"` ) means that the amount of space between tiles for devices greater than 600px width (bigger than phones) should be 8px.

Comment: But why for the single gridList in my codePen example all: md-cols-sm
md-cols-md
md-cols-gt-md
are used, and also I couldn't figure out their values, for example in following:
` <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6" md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="2:2" md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">`

Comment: do you know what is the css attribute behind the angular-material md-cols? if their is one at all..